# Allocate One Process for CRON job node.js

Tags: node.js, cron

I have done clustering in my Node.js application. I have a cron job service in my application which is started when I pass SRV_TYPE=cron environment variable to the app.js. The question is

I want that only one process will execute my cron job. 
This is code [shared on gist github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2f70a3241e29978514c59b6d8a9bf18d)

Comment: How about if you run an entirely separate app ( lets say cron ) that will be responsible for handling Cron jobs. This way you can separate the concerns. If you need to pass message/task from your main app to cron app, then you can use Rabbitmq for messaging system.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement this. You could run a separate instance for cron jobs. You could run cron jobs only on master.

I just wrote a small module for node, [cronivo](https://github.com/iudelsmann/cronivo), it uses laterJs and redis to allow a cron job to be executed only once even in cluster or multi process. Only the first available instance will execute the job. Any of the instances may execute the job, but only one.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
// In the master:
for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
  cluster.fork({ RUN_CRON : process.env.SRV_TYPE === "cron" && i === 0 });
}

// In the worker:
if (process.env.RUN_CRON === 'true') {
  ...create the scheduler...
}
```

In other words: you pass an environment variable `RUN_CRON` to each workers, and it will contain the string `true` if `SRV_TYPE` is set to `cron` *and* it's the first worker process that was forked.

Comment: I don't see the problem? Worker 1 is not logging the _"App is Starting on ..."_ message, so that will be the one running the cron part.